# Compute status: Not found: Tensor name "input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs" not found in checkpoint files

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using the CIFAR10 example. I trained the net as it is with the code provided. The training was done successfully. As I wanted to evaluate each example only once on my data set, I have modified inputs in cifar10_input.py to the following.

```py
def inputs(eval_data, data_dir, batch_size):
  filename = os.path.join(data_dir, TEST_FILE)
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename],num_epochs=1)
  image, label = read_and_decode(filename_queue)
  float_image = tf.image.per_image_whitening(image)
  min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue = 0.4
  min_queue_examples = int(NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_EVAL *
                           min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue)
  images, label_batch = tf.train.batch(
      [image, label],
      batch_size=batch_size,
      num_threads=1,
      capacity=min_queue_examples + 3 * batch_size)

  tf.image_summary('images', images)
  return images, tf.reshape(label_batch, [batch_size])
```

I have isolated the problem to the following:

> tf.train_string_input_producer([filename], num_epochs = 1)

If I don't set num_epochs = 1, everything works fine as it is. If I do, I get the following error.

```
0x2cf2700 Compute status: Not found: Tensor name "input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs" not found in checkpoint files /home/jkschin/tensorflow/my_code/data/svhn/train/model.ckpt-8000
```

Thank you for your help!

EDIT 3 @mrry:

It still fails. Here's the trace.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cnn_eval.py", line 148, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/default/_app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "cnn_eval.py", line 144, in main
    evaluate()
  File "cnn_eval.py", line 119, in evaluate
    saver = tf.train.Saver([v for v in variables_to_restore if v.name != "input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs"])
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'name'
```

EDIT 4 @mrry:

softmax_linear/biases/ExponentialMovingAverage

```
conv2/biases/ExponentialMovingAverage
local4/biases/ExponentialMovingAverage
local3/biases/ExponentialMovingAverage
softmax_linear/weights/ExponentialMovingAverage
conv1/biases/ExponentialMovingAverage
local4/weights/ExponentialMovingAverage
conv2/weights/ExponentialMovingAverage
input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs
local3/weights/ExponentialMovingAverage
conv1/weights/ExponentialMovingAverage

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cnn_eval.py", line 148, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/default/_app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "cnn_eval.py", line 144, in main
    evaluate()
  File "cnn_eval.py", line 119, in evaluate
    saver = tf.train.Saver([v for v in variables_to_restore if v != "input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 784, in __init__
    restore_sequentially=restore_sequentially)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 437, in build
    vars_to_save = self._ValidateAndSliceInputs(names_to_variables)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 340, in _ValidateAndSliceInputs
    names_to_variables = self._VarListToDict(names_to_variables)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 314, in _VarListToDict
    raise TypeError("Variable to save is not a Variable: %s" % var)
TypeError: Variable to save is not a Variable: Tensor("Const:0", shape=(), dtype=string)
```

EDIT 5 @mrry:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver([tf.Variable(0.0,validate_shape=False,name=v) for v in variables_to_restore if v != "input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs"])

0x21d0cb0 Compute status: Invalid argument: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [] rhs shape= [10]
     [[Node: save/Assign_8 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](softmax_linear/biases/ExponentialMovingAverage, save/restore_slice_8/_20)]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** In [`cifar10_eval.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/77c2042e77a11ee442ecc7e369cd91d91e4a98c3/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_eval.py#L134), change the saver constructor so that it is:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver([v for v in variables_to_restore
                        if v != "input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs"])
```

This problem arises because [`tf.train.string_input_producer()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#string_input_producer) internally creates a variable (called `"input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs"`) when its `num_epochs` argument is not `None`. When, in `cifar10_eval.py` a [`tf.train.Saver` is created](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/77c2042e77a11ee442ecc7e369cd91d91e4a98c3/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_eval.py#L134), it uses [`tf.all_variables()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#all_variables), which includes the implicitly-created variable from the `tf.nn.string_input_producer()`. This list of variables determines the set of names that TensorFlow looks up in the checkpoint file.

Currently there isn't a great way to refer to implicitly created variables, other than by their name. Therefore, the best fix is to exclude the variable from the `Saver` constructor by name.

Comment: I have changed tf.train.Saver accordingly but it does not work. Is there something more? Or did I miss something.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that! Can you try making the corresponding change in [`cifar10_eval.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/77c2042e77a11ee442ecc7e369cd91d91e4a98c3/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_eval.py#L134)? You'll have to exclude the implicitly created variable from `variables_to_restore`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on excluding the implicitly created variable? I used the line above as it is, and it does not seem to work. It's worth mentioning that the cifar10 code that I'm using (and the tensorflow installation) is not updated to the one on master.

Comment: I updated the answer with explicit instructions for fixing `cifar10_eval.py`. Let me know if that works!

Comment: It looks like `variables_to_restore` is a list of strings (not a list of `tf.Variable` objects as its name would suggest :)...). So you should just compare the strings with the name of the input producer's variable. I updated the answer to show how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, but it still does not work! Trace is in EDIT 4. I'm pretty sure the answer is really close now :)

Comment: Are you printing the contents of `tf.all_variables()` or `variables_to_restore` in your trace? I think there's something strange in `variables_to_restore`....

Comment: Well the latest trace says that it's not a Variable, so I tried initializing it to a Variable and got the error in EDIT 5.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104930/discussion-between-jkschin-and-mrry).

Answer (score 0):

Another way of eliminating the implicit variable `"input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs"` is to only load the trainable variables:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.trainable_variables())
```