# TensorFlow - how to evaluate all test set with every example once and only once

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am running [cifar10](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html) example from TensorFlow. But there is a problem for evaluation.

I have a test set and I want to evaluate every example from it once and only once. But the code ([line 121](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_eval.py#L121)) now only takes from an queue ([line 126](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py#L126)) which can not guarantee that. I have also made a modification that input is a '.tfrecords' file. Is there any suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems the problem is similar to this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35674073/compute-status-not-found-tensor-name-input-producer-limit-epochs-epochs-not), but I don't know how the solve it finally. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured a solution but rather imperfect. The clue is exclude it from variables to load and then initialize the `limit_epochs` by one's own. Following is the detailed step:

Add the code
`del variables_to_restore['input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs']` after `variables_to_restore = variable_averages.variables_to_restore()`. And it will stop loading `input_producer/limit_epochs` to the model.

Next, add the code `sess.run(tf.initialize_variables([v for v in tf.all_variables() if v.name.startswith("input_producer")]))` in a session to activate the variable.

In the end, do the operation `filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames, num_epochs=1)`.

And try to save the files before shutting down the threads.

The imperfection is you have to make every thread read only one example if you want it fits arbitrary test examples.

Answer (score 1):

The function [`tf.train.string_input_producer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#string_input_producer) that creates the queue of filenames [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py#L156) can accept an argument `num_epochs`. You can specify that you want it to run only 1 epoch.

```
# Create a queue that produces the filenames to read.
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames, num_epochs=1)
```

Comment: There is a problem behind it: the training has to take more than one epochs of examples; when I load the model, the TensorFlow will go wrong with following errors. `Tensor name "input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs" not found in checkpoint files`