# Tensorflow--how to limit epochs with evaluation only?

Tags: tensorflow

**Given that I train a model; save it off with metagraph/save.Saver, and the load that graph into a new script/process to test against test data, what is the best way to make sure I only iterate over the test data once?**

With my training data, I want to be able to iterate over the entire data set for an arbitrary number of iterations.  I use

```
tf.train.string_input_producer()
```

to drive a queue of loading files for training, so I can safely leave num_epochs as default (=None) and let other controls drive training termination.

However, when I run the graph for evaluation, I just want to the evaluate the test set once (and gather the appropriate statistics).

Initial attempted solution:

Make a tensor for Epochs, and pass that into tf.train.string_input_producer, and then tf.Assign it to the appropriate value based on test/train.

But:

tf.train.string_input_producer only takes integers as num_epochs, so this isn't possible...unless I'm missing something.

Further notes: I use

```
tf.train.batch()
```

to read-in test/train data that has been serialized into protocol buffers (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#file-formats), so I have minimal visibility into how the data is loaded and how far along it is.

tf.train.batch apparently will throw tf.errors.OutOfRangeError, but I'm not clear how to catch that successfully, or if that is even what I really want to do.  I tried a very naive

```
try...except...finally
```

(like in https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#creating-threads-to-prefetch-using-queuerunner-objects), which didn't catch the error from tf.train.batch.

Comment: Can you create two separate graphs with different `tf.train.string_input_producer`s and share the variables?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125436/tensorflow-how-to-evaluate-all-test-set-with-every-example-once-and-only-once for a convoluted way of achieving your goal.

Comment: @sygi yes totally could create two different graphs, it just feels...inelegant.  That said, maybe just the best thing to do.  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2514 also has some (possibly dated?) discussion/guidance around this, which suggests this overall is a little messier than I might hope.